# Not a Valid Jar When Running Hadoop Job

Tags: hadoop

I want to run WordCount Example.

In eclipse it run correctly. In output folder the output file is present.

I made a jar file of WordCount and want to run it through command

```
hadoop jar WordCount.jar /Projects/input /Projects/output
```

it gives me error

```
Not a valid JAR: /Projects/WordCount.jar
```

result of `hdfs dfs -ls /Projects`

```
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r-- 1 hduser supergroup 3418 2014-11-02 15:38 /Projects/WordCount.jar
drwxr-xr-x - hduser supergroup 0 2014-11-02 14:13 /Projects/input
drwxr-xr-x - hduser supergroup 0 2014-11-02 14:16 /Projects/output
```

it gives me same error on this also

```
  hadoop jar /Projects/WordCount.jar wordPackage.WordCount  /Projects/input /Projects/output

 Not a valid JAR: /Projects/WordCount.jar
```

how to solve this error.

I have run tvf command it gives this output

```
 jar -tvf /home/hduser/Desktop/Files/WordCount.jar

  60 Sun Nov 02 16:10:10 PKT 2014 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
 1895 Sun Nov 02 14:02:38 PKT 2014 wordPackage/WordCount.class
 1295 Sun Nov 02 14:02:38 PKT 2014 wordPackage/WordCount.java
 2388 Sun Nov 02 14:02:06 PKT 2014 wordPackage/WordReducer.class
 707 Sun Nov 02 14:02:06 PKT 2014 wordPackage/WordReducer.java
 2203 Sun Nov 02 14:02:08 PKT 2014 wordPackage/WordMapper.class
 713 Sun Nov 02 14:02:06 PKT 2014 wordPackage/WordMapper.java
 16424 Sun Nov 02 13:50:00 PKT 2014 .classpath
 420 Sun Nov 02 13:50:00 PKT 2014 .project
```

Comment: I think you missed to supply the MainClass file which should be something like $ bin/hadoop jar WordCount.jar org.myorg.WordCount /Projects/input /Projects/output

Comment: I have supplied main class. I have Edited question you can see in it.

Comment: The version of Hadoop you use to compile and build the jar should be the same version as that of the environment where you want to run the hadoop job (try the command: "hadoop version").

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot keep the jar in HDFS when executing the same using hadoop command, Jar should be available in the local path

If the jar is not runnable try the following (Need to specify the package.mainclass)

```
hadoop jar /home/hduser/Desktop/Files/WordCount.jar wordPackage.WordCount /Projects/input /Projects/output
```

If the jar is  runnable following can be used

```
hadoop jar /home/hduser/Desktop/Files/WordCount.jar /Projects/input /Projects/output
```

If the issue still persists, you need to rebuild this jar(WordCount.jar) in eclipse again

Comment: Yes, the jar should not be inside HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

in spite of rebuilding your jar again if issue still persists, Please make sure you have given +x(execution chmod 755) privileges before you run the command. in my case this was the reason for the issue.
command help:
**chmod +x jarname.jar**

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue. But in my case what I did was I wrote the java code referring to hadoop 1.x libraries and tried to execute it using 2.x. Initially, I got the same error in the terminal. Then I tried navigating to the path where I had my jar file. It worked.

May be you can actually try the following:(after navigating to the jar files path)

```
hadoop jar WordCount.jar  wordPackage.WordCount /Projects/input /Projects/output
```