# "Not A Valid Jar" When trying to run Map Reduce Job

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run a my MapReduce job by building a jar from eclipse , but while trying to execute the job , I am getting "Not a valid Jar" error.

I have tried to follow the link [Not a valid Jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26698567/not-a-valid-jar-when-running-hadoop-job) but that didnt help.

Can anyone please give me the instructions on how to build the jar from eclipse, for it to run on Hadoop.

I am aware of the process of building the Jar file from eclipse,however I am not sure, do I have to take any special care for building a jar file, so that it runs on Hadoop.

Comment: How are you trying to execute the jar? Through Oozie or Hue, or, through a command line? If command line, what command string are you using to attempt to execute the jar?

Comment: I am trying to execute the jar via command line and command I am using is ---  hadoop jar hist.jar Histogram "hdfs input path" "hdfs output path"

Comment: Are you sure that the jar file is in the directory where you run the application? 

You remember hist.jar is a relative path to the file.

Comment: So do we have to load all the jars in hdfs before executing our jar file in hadoop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit the command, make certain you have the following things on the line to do the command:

1. When you indicate the jar, make certain you are directing to the jar properly. It may be easiest to be certain by using the absolute path. To get the absolute path, if you navigate to the place where the jar is, then run 'readlink -f ' command to get the absolute path. So for you, not just hist.jar, but maybe /home/akash_user/jars/hist.jar or wherever it is on your system. If you are using Eclipse, it may be saving it somewhere funny, so make sure that is not the problem. The jar cannot be run from HDFS storage. must run from local storage.
2. When you name your main class, in your example Histogram, you must use the fully qualified name of the class, with the package, the project, and the class. So, usually, if the program/project is named Histogram, and there is a HistogramDriver, HistogramMapper, HistogramReducer, and your main() is in HistogramDriver, you need to type Histogram.HistogramDriver to get the program running. (Unless you made your jar runnable, which requires extra stuff at the beginning, making .mdf and things.)

Comment: Hi , I followed the above instruction but still I am facing the same problem.I am now trying wordcount example but I am facing the same problem. The command I am using is  :: hadoop jar /home/hduser/Desktop/WordCount.jar wordcount.WordCount.java /user/hduser/hdfsinput /user/hduser/hdfsoutput1    ..... I have not made my jar runnable, Its just a normal Import.... Still the same issue "Not a valid JAR: /home/hduser/Desktop/WordCount.jar"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the jar you are submitting (hist.jar) is in the current directory from where you are submitting the 'hadoop jar' command.

If the issue is still persisting, please tell the Java, Hadoop and Linux version you are using.

Comment: I am using Java Version 1.7, Hadoop 1.2.1 and Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

You should not keep the jar file in HDFS when executing the MapReduce job. Make sure Jar is available in the local path. Input path and output directory should be the path from HDFS.